# Метод Зейделя. Программа работает не для всех входных данных

Tags: pascal

Подскажите, почему программа работает не для всех входных данных? Как такое может быть? Одну СЛАУ она считает верно, а в другой даже ответа не выдает нормального.

```
var
  b,x:array [1..100] of real;
  a:array [1..100,1..100] of real;
  i,j,n:integer;
  E,R,S,d,W:real;
Begin
  writeln('Введите кол-во уравнений :');
  readln(n);
  writeln('Введите точность :');
  readln(E);
  for i:=1 to n do
  begin
    writeln ('введите коэффициенты в ',i,' строке');
    for j:=1 to n do
      readln (a[i,j]);
  end;
  writeln;
  writeln ('введите свободные члены');
  for i:=1 to n do
    readln (b[i]);
  repeat begin
    R:=0;
    for i:=1 to n do 
    begin
      s:=0;
      for j:=1 to n do
        if i<>j 
          then S:=S+a[i,j]*x[j];
      W:=(b[i]-S)/a[i,i];
      d:=abs(W-x[i]);
      if R<d 
        then begin 
          R:=d;
          x[i]:=W;
        end
        else x[i]:=W;
    end;
  end
  until (R<=E);
  for i:=1 to n do
    writeln('x=', x[i]);
  readln;
End.
```

Сама СЛАУ для примера:

```
a11=-1;
a12=2;
b1=3;
a21=3;
a22=-5;
b2=-4;
```

Должно получаться 7 и 5, а выдает -бесконечность в обоих случаях

Comment: Мне кажется, что лучший помощник здесь это DEBUG!

Comment: При чем здесь DEBUG?Нет никаких синтаксических ошибок,да и программа работает,но не для всех уравнений.Вопрос "почему ?".

Comment: А ты условия применимости метода проверил?

Comment: То есть, как? Вы жалуетесь на "не работает"(хотя само утверждение неверное) программа. Алгоритм работает, насколько я понял, не всегда так как нужно. Ну так вот для того что бы проверить где и как алгоритм сбоит используйте дебаг!

Comment: @Victor В смысле, в ручную ?

Comment: @vosure Вы знаете что такое дебаг?  Это отладка программы непосредственно в момент выполнения! И, да, можно сказать вручную!